# Setting size for individual size for scatter chart

Tags: lightningchart

can we change the size of individual scatter series items ? Right now this works to change the colour

pointSeries

```
 .add([
        { x: 2.5, y: 0, color: ColorRGBA( 255, 0, 0 ) },
        { x: 5, y: 10 },
        { x: 7.5, y: 20, color: ColorRGBA( 0, 255, 0 ) },
        { x: 10, y: 30, color: ColorRGBA( 0, 0, 255 ) },
    ])
```

something like

```
    { x: 2.5, y: 0, color: ColorRGBA( 255, 0, 0 ) , size : 2 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to specify the size of individual point of a [PointSeries](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/pointseries.html).

You need to enable individual point sizing with [`series.setIndividualPointSizeEnabled(true)`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/pointseries.html#setindividualpointsizeenabled) to enable the use of `size` field when adding new points. Then you can include the size info when adding the points to the series.  `series.add({ x: 2.5, y: 0, size: 30 })`

[`series.setPointSize`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/pointseries.html#setpointsize) can be used to define the size of points that do not have a individual size defined.

```js
const {
    lightningChart,
    IndividualPointFill,
    ColorRGBA
} = lcjs

const lc = lightningChart()
const chart = lc.ChartXY()

const series = chart.addPointSeries()

series.setIndividualPointSizeEnabled(true)
series.setPointFillStyle(new IndividualPointFill())
series.setPointSize(10)

series.add([
    { x: 2.5, y: 0, color: ColorRGBA(255, 0, 0), size: 30 },
    { x: 5, y: 10 },
    { x: 7.5, y: 20, color: ColorRGBA(0, 255, 0), size: 5  },
    { x: 10, y: 30, color: ColorRGBA(0, 0, 255), size: 20  },
])
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@2.2.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you ! is there anyway we can set the border  color with thickness ?

Comment: LightningChart JS doesn't yet support border color on point series. This feature is something that we hope to implement in future versions.

Comment: Thanks , can you check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106335/zoom-only-the-x-axis-of-chart-lightning-js