# zoom only the x axis of chart lightning js

Tags: lightningchart

How do I zoom only the x axis  when I swipe up via touchpad  , and pan to left or right when i swipe left or right

```
 chart[1].getDefaultAxisY()
  .setScrollStrategy(undefined)
  .setInterval(-250,250)
```

Also I want to zoom  the x axis with full height of y axis no matter where  i click and drag in the screen.Is this possible  ? Thanks

[image]

Also Can I control the scroll behaviour with custom functions like If i wish to scroll by keeping last value of series fixed , I don't know how to explain but something like this

```
onScroll()
    {
    axisX.setInterval(X,250);
    }
```

Where here 250 is fixed but X value varies from 0 to 249 as we scroll .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable axis chart interactions with [`axis.setChartInteractions(false)`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/axis.html#setchartinteractions). This will disable zooming by mouse wheel, zoom by drag, fit by drag and pan by drag for the axis. Meaning that when the zooming interaction is done only the X axis would zoom.

Alternatively you can control each of the interactions individually.
[`axis.setChartInteractionFitByDrag`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/axis.html#setchartinteractionfitbydrag)
[`axis.setChartInteractionPanByDrag`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/axis.html#setchartinteractionpanbydrag)
[`axis.setChartInteractionZoomByDrag`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/axis.html#setchartinteractionzoombydrag)
[`axis.setChartInteractionZoomByWheel`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/axis.html#setchartinteractionzoombywheel)

You can also disable interactions on the axis.

- [`axis.setMouseInteractions`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/axis.html#setmouseinteractions)
- [`axis.setAxisInteractionPanByDragging`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/axis.html#setaxisinteractionpanbydragging)
- [`axis.setAxisInteractionReleaseByDoubleClicking`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/axis.html#setaxisinteractionreleasebydoubleclicking)
- [`axis.setAxisInteractionZoomByDragging`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/axis.html#setaxisinteractionzoombydragging)
- [`axis.setAxisInteractionZoomByWheeling`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/axis.html#setaxisinteractionzoombywheeling)
- [`axis.setNibInteractionScaleByDragging`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/axis.html#setnibinteractionscalebydragging)
- [`axis.setNibInteractionScaleByWheeling`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/axis.html#setnibinteractionscalebywheeling)

To keep the axis interval end value at a single value you can attach a listener to the [`onScaleChange`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/axis.html#onscalechange) event on the axis. This event is called when ever the scale of the axis has changed. The event handler will receive the start and end values of the next interval when the interval changes. In the handler you can force the interval end value to be constant.

```js
const axisX = chart.getDefaultAxisX()

axisX.onScaleChange((start, end) => {
    if (end !== 250)
        axisX.setInterval(start, 250, false, true)
})
```

```js
const {
  lightningChart,
  SolidLine,
  SolidFill,
  ColorRGBA,
  AxisTickStrategies,
  UIOrigins,
  DataPatterns,
  Themes
} = lcjs

const {
  createProgressiveTraceGenerator
} = xydata

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries()

const lineSeries2 = chart.addLineSeries()

const generator = createProgressiveTraceGenerator()
  .setNumberOfPoints(250)

const dataSets = [
  generator
  .generate()
  .toPromise(),

  generator
  .generate()
  .toPromise()
]

Promise.all(dataSets)
  .then((data) => {
    lineSeries.add(data[0])
    lineSeries2.add(data[1])
  })

chart.getDefaultAxisY()
  .setChartInteractionFitByDrag(false)
  .setChartInteractionZoomByDrag(false)
  .setChartInteractionPanByDrag(false)
  .setChartInteractionZoomByWheel(false)

// setup handler to keep interval end at 250
const axisX = chart.getDefaultAxisX()
axisX.onScaleChange((start, end) => {
  if (end !== 250)
    axisX.setInterval(start, 250, false, true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/xydata@1.4.0/dist/xydata.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@2.2.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi , when I keep xvalue greater than my chart length I get maximum call stack size error.

Comment: charts[chartIndex].getDefaultAxisX().setInterval(start,   xVal+20, false,true);  is not working  , but charts[chartIndex].getDefaultAxisX().setInterval(start,   xVal, false,true); is working fine.

Comment: If the value of xVal is dependent on the axis interval then you will run in to a call stack size error as the onScaleChange event will be fired recursively. If the xVal is not dependent on the interval, make sure that you are checking if the interval with the xVal + 20 would be same as it currently is.